# Конкурсно-рекомендованные вопросы или наоборот

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На вкладке конкурсных вопросов по метке ([например, perl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=featured&pageSize=30)) название вкладки "конкурсные" не соответствует описанию "рекомендуемые вопросы":

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там же:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ещё:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо бы сделать однозначное описание.

Comment: Замечу ещё, что есть некая схожесть между  словами **конкурс** и **соревнование**, которые означают здесь разные понятия.

Comment: @4per `соревнование` вроде как только в метке есть.

Comment: @alexolut я то различаю эти понятия. Но для новичков может быть не очень понятно, не смотря на то что `соревнование` лишь метка.

Comment: @4per думаете, из-за этого могут быть какие-то проблемы?

Comment: а из-за сабжа могут быть проблемы? ровно также и с этим.. я думаю.

Comment: @4per В сабже конкретная проблема в несогласованности терминов из-за перевода разными людьми. А Ваша мысль мне не до конца понятна. p.s. не забывайте добавлять ник в ответ, а то уведомления не приходят :)

Comment: @alexolut давайте продолжим общение в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать везде вариант, образованный от слова "конкурс".

Ссылки из transifex:

- [You are on the featured tab](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265306?key=fd04a08420dc24f140c02fbf51d9494f)

  > Вы находитесь на вкладке «конкурсные вопросы».
- [featured questions tagged](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265289?key=ddebfeebac717ad35550e1ce63d2ecd3) (с учётом множественных форм)

  > конкурсных вопросов по метке
- [featured questions feed](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264802?key=766adb317fb89dc13470a677bea21c27)

  > лента конкурсных вопросов
- [featured $htmltags$ questions feed](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265276?key=59ecf63a43c134b3aad65bc1bbc716f0)

  > лента конкурсных вопросов $htmltags$
- [featured $tag1$ or $tag2$ or $tag3$ or ($rest$ more) questions feed](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265267?key=06baefbbbacabe0975cf6d1d22bceae9) (есть множественные формы, но не очень ясно к чему они относятся)

  > лента конкурсных вопросов: $tag1$ или $tag2$ или $tag3$ или (других: $rest$)

**Обновил строки на основании предложенного списка. Должно появиться на сайте после следующей подгрузки transifex.**